# Match not whole text in column for reference

Tags: r, text, merge

I have two data files. The first is a 'master sheet' where I am compiling data, with the relevant columns looking like:

```
Family          ID                     Size
Tyrannidae      Empidonax traillii
Tyrannidae      Empidonax atriceps
Conopophagidae  Conopophaga lineata
```

Where size is the column I am wanting to fill in. I need for future analysis ID to contain both the genus and species names. The size data is based on the genus (the first word in ID) in a separate file like this:

```
 Genus        Size
Empidonax     13
Conopophaga   6
```

Is there a way in R to say matching certain, not all, text in the ID column to be able to then fill in the Size column? Desired result

```
Family          ID                     Size
Tyrannidae      Empidonax traillii     13
Tyrannidae      Empidonax atriceps     13
Conopophagidae  Conopophaga lineata    6
```

Or would it just be simpler to split the ID column into two, fill in Size and then merge the two back together?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data.table` enables `X[Y]` it seems very appropriate. Therefore, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
master <- data.table(Family=c("Tyrannidae", "Tyrannidae", "Conopophagidae"), 
          ID = c("Empidonax traillii", "Empidonax traillii", "Conopophaga lineata"))
dt <- data.table(Genus = c("Empidonax", "Conopophaga"), Size = c(13, 6))

# get Genus
master[, Genus := gsub(" .*$", "", ID)] # master$ID replaced by ID
# set key to Genus
setkey(master, "Genus")
> master[dt] # X[Y]

#          Genus         Family                  ID Size
# 1:   Empidonax     Tyrannidae  Empidonax traillii   13
# 2:   Empidonax     Tyrannidae  Empidonax traillii   13
# 3: Conopophaga Conopophagidae Conopophaga lineata    6
```

Comment: Thanks to you both, that is a really useful function

Answer (score 4):

If `master` and `size` are your data frames, you could create a Genus column and then use `merge` to get the combined data frame.

```
#regex deletes all characters after a space
master$Genus <- gsub(" .*$","",master$ID) 
merge(master,size,by="Genus")
```